# Easiest way to convert many CDN links to local files

Tags: html, css, apache, cdn, httpserver

I want to deploy an open source website to my local area network.

The problem is that there are tons of CDN links in the code of this website, like the following:

```html
3590     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
3591     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
3592     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" />
3593     <?php if (FM_USE_HIGHLIGHTJS): ?>
3594     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/<?php echo FM_HIGHLIGHTJS_STYLE ?>.     min.css">
```

These CDN links can't be accessed because I'm in a local area network.

One solution I thought up is to download all of them to local machine, and modify all links of CDN to local files.

But there are too many CND links, so I gave up.

Is there anyway that doesn't need to change the code? For example, cahce these files in HTTP server(But I don't know how to do, I'm using Apache)?

Comment: Are all the files used by each page the same? I would imagine you will find different files on different pages - so writing something to download them automatically will need to be either pointed at each page or you will need to write something to crawl each page to find other pages within the site to then store all the file paths.

What is the reason behind deploying it locally? Just so you can read it offline?

Comment: @UrbanwarfareStudios Yes I want to read it offline.